# While Integrating Paypal why i got this Error?

Tags: iphone

Please Anyone can tell me why i got this kind of error:

```
ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

Comment: Might want to put that long line in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: And what is the data you are sending to PayPal? It seems like you're not sending the right thing.

Comment: Also, as has been noted in a number of your other posts, an iPhone app will likely be rejected if it contains PayPal elements. In-app purchasing is *the way* to do this.

Comment: It is also important to remind that the method is a case-sensitive field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code is 81002 and the message is "Specified Method is not Supported". Post your code and you may get better answers.

You can also check the [PayPal API Error Codes Reference](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_errorcodes) for any error message you receive. The particular error message you posted is a Validation Error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are doing GET requests vs POST.

Answer (score -1):

If I had to guess, I'd say that you're trying to call a method that is not supported.